# R: matching pattern with leading period

Tags: r

I'm using R's *list.files* function to pull the full name of a file who's name matches the following actual characters

```
   .test_
```

and has a file extension of xlsx (the full file name is *.test_2022-05-23.xlsx*).

When I execute the following syntax

```
des <- list.files(path = raw, pattern = "\\.test_.*\\.xlsx$")
```

, *des* resolves as character(0).

Apparently the leading

```
\\.
```

is not correct?

If I remove the leading period from the actual file's name and execute the following command

```
des <- list.files(path = raw, pattern = "test_.*\\.xlsx$")
```

, des resolves to the expected

```
test_2022-05-23.xlsx
```

.

What should I set pattern equal to to match the file's name when the name begins with a period?

Thanks for your help,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set `all.files=T` like this:

```
des <- list.files(path = raw, pattern = "\\.test_.*\\.xlsx$", all.files=T)
```